# What prospect is there for foreign language look-up in Kindle for PC?

Tags: dictionaries, kindle-pc-reader

Kindle for PC is currently ineligible for delivery of most dictionaries on the "Manage Your Content and Devices" page, and so cannot use them for word look-up.

Is this situation likely to change soon? Or is there some deep reason for it, which is likely to make it last a long time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this situation likely to change soon? Or is there some deep reason for it, which is likely to make it last a long time?

IMHO, Amazon most likely hasn't updated the Kindle for Windows and OSX apps, because not enough readers demanded custom dictionary support. (BTW, Amazon-bought dictionaries can be sent to the Kindle for Android app.)

Until Amazon fixes this, you can outsmart the Kindle for PC/OSX/iOS apps by changing the ASIN number of your custom dictionary to the ASIN number of one of the default dictionaries and overwriting the default dictionary with your custom dictionary. This involves the following steps:

1. Remove the DRM from the custom dictionary that you want to use.
2. Download a dictionary that you won't use, e.g. the American English dictionary (*B003ODIZL6*_EBOK.azw).
3. Open your dictionary with [Java Mobi Metadata
   Editor](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?p=1927698), change the existing ASIN entries to *B003ODIZL6*, save
   the file, rename it to *B003ODIZL6*_EBOK.azw and copy it to the My
   Kindle Content folder. (If your dictionary doesn't have ASIN entries, click the (+) button and select 113 ASIN *and* 504 ASIN.)

Obviously, you'd use the ASIN number of the French monolingual dictionary, if you wanted to replace the default monolingual French dictionary with a bilingual dictionary etc.

Comment: Well there's not much demand for the poor foreign language tools that are being offered. Someday Kindle will be a valuable asset in foreign language learning. But for now Kindle considers a few million foreign-language students around the word too small a niche market to justify any effort. Even a Kindle book on digital technology for learning Chinese, which recommends several tools for learning to read the language, does not mention Kindle as a resource! That book is _Chinese Is Not Really That Hard: A Guide to Using Technology to Learn Chinese_[Kindle Edition] By: Sia Mohajer